# Error: Failed to convert: Database Connections... when trying to export to shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arccatalog

I have created a table with some derived data in SDE using SQL server.  The following is an example row of the table:

```
T_OBJECTID  T_GEOID T_STATE T_COUNTY    T_TRACT T_NAME  T_LSAD  T_CENSUSAREA    T_SHAPE T_SUM_POP10 T_SUM_ALAND T_SUM_AWATER    T_SUM_LandPlusWater T_AreaDif   T_PerCha    T_PopDen
699 1400000US01027959000    AL  027 959000  9590    Tract   69.34400000 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
```

When I go to export the table from the database connections to a shapefile I keep getting the following error:

> Failed to convert:  Database
>   Connections\xxxxxxx.sde\sde_xxxxxxxxxxx_Table...

Please note that the credentials for the connection are correct.

**EDIT:**

It is also important to note the following:

The original data was imported to SQL Server using ArcCatalog into SDE. That data was then manipulated to get derived values; I did this as SDE administrator. The derived data table can now be seen in the Database Connection directory in ArcCatalog. I was advised to right click on table and then register as versioned (but was grayed out) then was advised that I should be able to just export it as shapefile because all the shape data is in the table; these advisements did not work.

Why am I getting this error?

**EDIT2:**
one thing though I noticed is when I first right click on the table it states "Error opening feature class - attribute column not found" Is it because I renamed the columns in SQL Server?

Comment: Is there a way to expand the error message in the results window or is the error message just a ppup window?. Did you create the data using SQL Server or an ESRI product? Is the data viewable/queryable before you try to export it? Try to run the validate geometry tool on the SDE data before you try to export it.

Comment: The original data was imported to SQL Server using ArcCatalog into SDE.  That data was then manipulated to get derived values; I did this as sde administrator.  The derived data table can now be seen in the Database Connection directory.  i was to right click on table and then register as Versioned (but was grayed out) then was advised that I should be able to just export it as shapefile because all the shape data is in the table

Comment: This is useful information, you should edit your question to include it. To export the SDE data are you right clicking on it and choosing export in ArcCatalog? Have you tried using any of the Geoprocessing tools such as table to dbase (if you only want the .dbf) or Feature Class To Shapefile?

Comment: @Dowlers I'm very new to ArcGIS.  How do you propose that I re-word my question? - sorry for delay in response. I had to go run an errand

Comment: Use the edit button on your question to copy and paste the extra information from your comment above to the question. This will help others answer.  Have you tried using any of the Geoprocessing tools such as table to dbase (if you only want the .dbf) or Feature Class To Shapefile?

Comment: I've been brute forcing alot of tools.  I think I might be getting somewhere

Comment: Not sure what you mean by brute forcing tools. The geoprocessing tools tend to work or not. But they give better error messages then use using the ArcCatalog interface.

Comment: Ive tried to make dBase, export to feature class (single and multiple), send to geoDatabase...nothing seems to work

Comment: In ArcCatalog click geoprocessing<results and then in the results window  navigate to the failed processes. Expand them and look for error messages in the Messages section. If you see anything add them to you question.

Comment: I only get a warning sign (yellow triangle with exclamation point in it) with the error stated in the title; one thing though I noticed is when I first right click on the table it states `"Error opening feature class - attribute column not found"`  Is  it because I renamed the columns in SQL Server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26675/discussion-between-dowlers-and-user216392).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing feature class column names directly in SQL Server will often corrupt the feature class as SDE keeps track of column names behind the scenes.

Change the column names back to to their original names in SQL Server.